# I am not able to insert data into a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am facing a problem while inserting the data into my SQL Server database. I am working on school management system. I have 2 users (Admin and Staff). Admin creates/sets all the basic needs for the staff to work with.

Here, admin is adding class details. So, the first step is to add a class, section and strength into the `STDMS_ClassDetails` database. Later, subjects fields will be updated.

Now, the flow for adding new class goes like this:

1. Under create class tab, Admin sets the range of classes. eg: class 1 to class 10.
2. Then admin selects how to add the sections, strength of class.

   2.i. If he selects 1by1 option, then he needs to select each class, section & strength of class.

   2.ii. If he selects group option, then at once all the above classes will have the same no of sections and strength of the class.

This is my database.

[image: Database]

& This is my front end.

[image: Front End]

There was no error messages, however the database is not updating. So, there must be something I am missing in this code. Please help me rectifying and making this code work.

My code looks like this:

```
Private Sub btnCCSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCCSave.Click
    If MsgBox("You are going to add new classes into your database." + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + "Are you sure?", vbInformation + vbYesNo, "Add new classes.") = vbYes Then
        If rb_1by1.Checked = True Then
            con.Open()
            Try
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO STDMS_ClassDetails(Class_ID, Section, Class_Strength) VALUES(@d1, @d2, @d3)", con)
                    With cmd
                        For i As Integer = 1 To updownTotalSections.Value
                            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", Integer.Parse(cbCCClass.Text))
                            Select Case i
                                Case 1
                                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", "A")
                                    Exit Select
                                Case 2
                                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", "B")
                                    Exit Select
                                Case 3
                                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", "C")
                                    Exit Select
                                Case 4
                                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", "D")
                                    Exit Select
                                Case 5
                                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", "E")
                                    Exit Select
                            End Select
                            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@d3", updownTotalStrength.Value)
                        Next
                    End With
                End Using
                con.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
        ElseIf rb_Group.Checked = True Then
            Try
                MsgBox("try")
                For i As Integer = updownLB.Value To updownUP.Value
                    MsgBox("for i = " + i.ToString)
                    For j As Integer = 1 To updownTotalSections.Value
                        MsgBox("for j = " + j.ToString)
                        con.Open()
                        MsgBox("con open")
                        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO STDMS_ClassDetails(Class_ID, Section, Class_Strength) VALUES(@d1, @d2, @d3)", con)
                            With cmd
                                MsgBox("Ready query and cmd")
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", i)
                                MsgBox("added first col")
                                Select Case j
                                    Case 1
                                        MsgBox("case1")
                                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", "A")
                                        MsgBox("added1")
                                        Exit Select
                                    Case 2
                                        MsgBox("case2")
                                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", "B")
                                        MsgBox("added2")
                                        Exit Select
                                    Case 3
                                        MsgBox("case3")
                                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", "C")
                                        MsgBox("added3")
                                        Exit Select
                                    Case 4
                                        MsgBox("case4")
                                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", "D")
                                        MsgBox("added4")
                                        Exit Select
                                    Case 5
                                        MsgBox("case5")
                                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", "E")
                                        MsgBox("added5")
                                        Exit Select
                                End Select
                                MsgBox("out of select")
                                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@d3", updownTotalStrength.Value)
                                MsgBox("added strength")
                                con.Close()
                                MsgBox("closed")
                            End With
                        End Using
                        MsgBox("end")

                    Next
                Next

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
        End If
      End If
   End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: you never execute the query

Comment: Haha... My bad... Thanks

Comment: you need to execute your command. just add cmd.ExecuteNonQuery inside your loop (at the end).

Comment: Terminology: what you are calling a "*database*" is actually called a "*table*" in SQL DBMS's.  A database contains your tables (and views, stored procedures and other SQL objects).

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following command before The `End Using` Line

```
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

because you built your command but you didn't execute it